# 403 forbidden error while updating a product

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

While updating a product I am getting the below error

[image]

So when I checked the ajax request it is returning a 403 forbidden error. The error is happening for only some products. Other products are getting updated. The ajax request is `admin/catalog/product/validate/id/3209/type/simple/store/0/set/4/key/1bf9ffe87ef4731b231675a326e8040fefeac64590034673g3b4527y3fba8c79/?isAjax=true`